# Jquery not working/rendering in ie9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, cross-browser

I have looked everywhere and cant seem to find an answer that works for my problem. I have got my site working in ie 6, 7 ,8 ,10, firefox and chrome and then i looked on ie9 and almost passed out. The styling was broken and none of the jQuery was working.

I have added in the  ie8 compatibility mode and that seems to have sorted my styling issue:

```
meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

However this has still not sorted my jquery issue. Its as if its not registering that there is any such thing as jQuery. I have read articled saying that it has to be jquery v 1.6 or later, and consequently i am using:

```
script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
```

I am just baffled as to how it works perfectly in all the other browsers and then ie9 has lost the plot. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Have you tried directly referencing jQuery 1.7.1 rather than using Google's CDN? [http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js)

Comment: Do you have any sort of <!--[if lt IE 9]> tricks?

Comment: Hi jakeclarkson, yeah i have just added in jQuery 1.7 directly and still have the same issue :(

Comment: and JP Hellemons, i have a lt IE8, but nothing that references ie9 atall

Comment: Can you post some code please?
Perhaps it's because of a class problem?

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks for your answers.
I was using IETester, and its rendering ie9 without jQuery. I just made a virtual PC and downloaded actual ie9 and its fine. My fault sorry for wasting peoples time.

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix to display stylesheets in IE9 ... In this case I was using a Jquery mobile style sheet with a full URL reference to the stylesheet.  But regardless try using the following code and relatively referencing your stylesheet ... IE9 began to work correctly:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile-1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: You just needed to mark the line as code and it then indents and shows correctly.